# Word meaning: "containing no electronic components"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to find a single academic-sounding word that means: "containing no electric parts" or "containing no electronic components"

I originally thought "*analog*" would work here, but after double checking the definition, I have reconsidered.

I can easily think of a few examples, but the naming convention does not seem universal. Take:

> electric drill > hand drill
>
> mower > push mower (antique)

In contrast to the above, I want a word that can be applied to any object.

Here is a sentence I had in mind:

> Automobiles manufactured before the 1980's are typically _________.

Comment: I can’t find a definitive reference, but to me *mechanical* suggests a simpler, electrics-free device.

Answer (score 1):

> free of electronics
>
> electronics-free
>
> mechanical
>
> hand

However, none of these work with your car example

> Automobiles manufactured before the 1980's are typically _________.

because cars included electric starters since the '20s.

It seems you are referring to computers or semiconductors, so you could say

> computer-free
>
> semiconductor-free

Comment: Not to mention spark plugs!